# Do questioners get new notifications (both on the web and email) when an answer is edited?

Tags: support, answers, notifications

A user asks a question. I write a useful answer. Later, 20 mins to a week, I update the answer either short, a typo fix, or long, doubling the length of the answer with some new info or an example.

Does the questioner get a new notification that I updated the answer for them and there is more info for them to look at?

If not then I probably need to leave a comment "I updated the answer, please take a look". If they do get a notification then no need to leave the comment.

Seems like this should be semi-automated so if it's a relatively large edit the questioner gets a notification and if it's a small edit maybe not? It seems like there is some similar threshold for whether or not a question appears on the newest questions list. I don't know what that criteria is. Might just be time since last edit?

Stack Overflow is trying to be friendly to questioners. Telling them "Hey, there's a huge update to an answer someone left you" seems more friendly than nothing.

Answer (score 3):

No, question askers do not get notifications when an answer to their question is edited.

And it's good thing, since most edits revolve about minute details like spelling, grammar, or even style. Getting notifications for something like that would be entirely too noisy.

Comment: Wow, that's un-incredibliy short sited opinion and entirely unfriendly to questioners since if someone made a large edit the questioner misses out on all the effort the answerer gave them, they miss out on insightful info, and they may miss out on important corrections.

Comment: There is *possibly* times when you might want to notify OP about a big change. Few times I've had to either completely edit an answer or add an entirely new section to it about something I initially missed. So there *might* be a "notify question owner for this edit" option. Yet at the same time, you can always just @ them to explain "Hey, I added X in order to address Y" for example. That's what I've done. Seems to work well enough, so I'd also see there being no need for an extra feature. Ultimately, I'd class it as "nice to have" but not a necessary thing.

Comment: @gman - It would be brutal on your notifications if you ask a question that attracts multiple pages of answers, would you really want a notification for every tweak that get applied to any answer?

Comment: @Sayse, I never suggested you should get notified of every tweak.

Comment: @gman *incredibly *shortsighted. See, the number of times I've edited really bad English (not that your comments was really bad) in even accepted answers makes me think this might not work as well as one might hope. I think the current workaround, the ability to add a comment @ notifying the user of substantial edits, seems like the best compromise. You are able to be as friendly as you want to be, and I can edit pigeon English into proper English without alerting everyone.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, by your argument you shouldn't even get a notification for the original answer. If you want the user to be notified you should leave them a comment. Ridiculous. At worst S.O. should notify if the edit is over some threshold. At best there should be a button/checkbox (notify user). That's much better than spamming comments with "left an update (blalblalblalbal min comment length - will delete once you acknowledge that this comment is no longer useful to you since it is entirely useless to anyone else"

Comment: @gman By my argument, people would continue getting notified as they are currently, so they would continue getting a notification for the original answer. I'm not sure where in my comment I implied otherwise. Only *edits* would require the editor to comment *if they think it is worthy of the attention of the OP*. If someone updating their post can't think of text more informative than "left an update", that's on them. The few times I've felt the need to inform anyone I've updated an answer, I've listed what I changed and why -- I felt that was more welcoming than making the person do a diff...

Comment: Your comment suggest that if I want the questioner to be notified I should leave a comment. That argument can be made just was much for the original answer. Don't spam the user with a notification period. Require a comment. You seem to think the original answer should be automated. I think siginficant edits should also be automated. That won't cause notification spam and it will prevent comment spam. A win/win

Comment: Maybe you want to take the conversation to the question?